# The biggest artificial cloud ever made

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> Bigger than a boy, heavier than a fatty.
>   Even though I had lost some weight, still the only one on a flight.
>   I do split, I do combine, and I split for a greater one.
>   On a icy island I was lit, yet no human got a hit.
>   For a phone call you couldn't hold, as I traveled throughout the world.

**What am I?**

Comment: Surely Amazon's cloud is the biggest; it spans the whole planet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is

> [Tsar Bomba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsar_Bomba), a Soviet nuclear bomb and the most powerful nuke ever detonated.

*The biggest artificial cloud ever made*

> The [mushroom cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mushroom_cloud) for Tsar Bomba, according to Wikipedia, was about 64 km high (over seven times the height of Mount Everest), and the cap had a peak width of 95 km.

**Additional Explanation from OP:**

> A mushroom cloud scale also has it.
>  [image: image from atomichertiage.org]

*Bigger than a boy, heavier than a fatty.*

> It was bigger than [Little Boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Boy) and heavier than [Fat Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_Man).

*Even though I had lost some weight, still the only one on a flight.*

> Tsar Bomba was flown to its test site by a specially modified plane.

**Additional explanation from OP:**

> The [blast yield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TNT_equivalent) initially planned for making Tsar Bomba was 100 megatons of TNT, but this was halved due to the nuclear fallout issue.

*I do split, I do combine, and I split for a greater one.*

> [Fission bombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fission_bomb) derive their energy from nuclear fission (splitting), but Tsar Bomba was one of the more powerful (greater) [thermonuclear weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermonuclear_weapon) involve both fusion (combining) and fission.

*On a icy island I was lit, yet no human got a hit.*

> Tsar Bomba was dropped in Novaya Zemlya, an icy island in the north of Russia.

*For a phone call you couldn't hold, as I traveled throughout the world.*

**Explanation from OP:**

> Radio communications all over the world were interrupted for almost one hour as Tsar Bomba exploded, and this thermonuclear weapon's shockwave travelled more than 3 times around the world.

Comment: Dear sir al'thor, I expected the riddle should be easy in a way, but the answer just merely reached the brink of the true one. If you have known those two Yankees, you should put *something else specific* into consideration.

Comment: @ShaneHsu The "two Yankees" being Little Boy and Fat Man? Does that mean the answer is *one specific* nuclear bomb?

Comment: Sure they are, but the true one is actually *something else*.

Comment: Ha! You've found the right one. If you don't mind, may I edit about some explanation about those lines?

Comment: @ShaneHsu I just edited with better explanations; I think I've now got everything except the last line.

Comment: Alright, then. I will pick edit explanation for the last line.

Comment: Forgot the explanation on "lose some weight", maybe a further edit is alright?

Comment: @ShaneHsu Sure, go ahead! :-)

Comment: Now that's just ridiculous! It took me longer to just read the title (never mind the loading of the page).