# A rebus with only letters

Tags: rebus

Solve the following rebus.

> THINBOXKING

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is clearly

> THINKING OUTSIDE THE BOX.

Comment: I didn't think it would take too long for someone to solve this, but that was impressively fast. I can't event accept an answer yet!

Comment: You almost broke your own personal best (unicorn).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Unicorn [isn't even my best](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/43298/5373) :-)